# How relationship laravel auth

Tags: laravel, authentication, relationship

I write admin panel for my website, I have tables ;

**authorities**

- id
- name

**roles**

- id
- name

**role_authorities**

- id
- role_id
- authority_id

**user_roles**

- id
- user_id
- role_id
- section

I want to in that user login , if user->mission  == 1  so user is admin, I get roles and roles_authorities so I have authorities for user.

How make to relationship ?

tnx

Comment: you want to user table to make relationships with roles and roles_authorities  tables ?

Comment: yes,I want to user relationship roles and roles_authorities

Comment: do you have models to each table?

Comment: Yes, I have models to each tables

Comment: authorities is a really confusing name....shouldn't that be permissions??? role_permissions and not authorities I mean!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**user**

```
class user{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserRoles');//pathe to UserRoles model
    }
}
```

**user_roles**

```
class UserRoles{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role');//path to role model
    }
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\user');//path to user model
    }
}
```

**role_authorities**

```
class RoleAuthorities{
     public function role()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Role');//path to role model
        }
     public function authorities()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Authorities');//path to Authorities model
        }
    }
```

so you can call like this:

```
 foreach(User::find(1)->roles as $roleItem){
     echo $roleItem->role()->name;
}
```

> I strongly suggest to use third party package.
>   https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust